# google-api-java-client library not working in android

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google's places API.  I downloaded `google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip` library and I'm using source code from https://github.com/tuthan/Google-Place-Api-Demo

I import the external library in exactly the correct way, but the code still give me compile time errors on all imports of `google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip`.

e.g.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
```

I've been working on this for a week, but have been unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency jars are not in your classpath. Please add the jar from google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip to your sample project.

Comment: thanks i have added and it works fine now, can you tell me about pom.xml?? My sample project runs without pom.xml file correctly, then whats the need of including this file???

Comment: pom.xml is a Maven artifact. If you are using eclipse build and not using Maven for building the project, you can ignore it/delete it. Its like your ant build.xml